# Can I preload and cache images using React VR?

Tags: browser-cache, preload, react-360

I'm making a virtual tour in a house using React VR and would preload next panorama image when the user transport from room. After preload I would use the image from the local disk cache.

I've tried this code below

```
<Pano style={{ display: 'none' }} source={asset(`360/${this.thePanoImage}`)} />
```

But it doesn't see on image below.

[image: Network output]

Above the red line is when the virtual tour is loading for the first time. You see `leefruimte.jpg` is downloaded in nine milliseconds. After transportation *(under the red line)*, `leefruimte.jpg` is downloaded again, but now in twelve milliseconds.

I'm accepting that the image `leefruimte.jpg` was taken from the loaded image in scene zero and was cached.

Also the images `navigationCircle.png` and `focusspot.png`, wouldn't be preloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: This is most likely going to change in the future, but at the time of writing, you can look into the [Prefetch](https://github.com/facebook/react-360/blob/master/React360/js/Views/Prefetch.js) component.

Prefetch only works with Panos at the time, but it looks like it's enough for your current needs.

```
import {Prefetch} from 'react-vr';
...
...
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <Prefetch key={someUniqueKey} source={asset(`360/${this.thePanoImage}`)} />
        ...
    );
}
```

`Pano`'s [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-360/blob/master/React360/js/Views/Pano.js) checks for `Prefetch`'s cache when loading an image. So when you try and load the `Pano` for `this.thePanoImage` next, the image should be available in the cache and won't be fetched a second time.

Comment: Link to the new Prefect: https://github.com/facebook/react-360/blob/master/React360/js/Views/Prefetch.js